# How to insert DOCTYPE element in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have some production code which generates an XML file in the following way:

1. Generate a string by using XmlSerializer with an instance of a class with XmlAttributes
2. Generate XmlDocument by using LoadXml() with the string generated in step 1
3. Write to file using XmlWriter wrapping a StringWriter

It is now required that a DOCTYPE declaration is included. I want to make as few changes as possible to the code.

The only way I have managed to do this so far is:

```
tx.WriteDocType("entitytype", null, "http://testdtd/entity.dtd", null);                    
foreach (XmlNode node in document)
{
  if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
  {
    document.RemoveChild(node);
  }
}
document.WriteTo(tx);
```

This seems to be a bit of a hack - is there a better way I can insert a DOCTYPE declaration? In particular is there a way I can avoid having an XmlDeclaration in the XmlDocument generated by the LoadXml() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps more steps in the conversion are necessary, but on serialization the xml declaration can be removed by using an instance of `XmlWriterSettings` configured as follows.

```
var iSettings = new XmlWriterSettings{ OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to include an XML Declaration when writing with the XmlWriter - the problem is the XML Declaration which is added to the XmlDocument created by the LoadXml(). This has to be removed before I can add the DOCTYPE using WriteDocType().

Comment: Generating the `DocType` inf the way you do it seems to be the correct way to me.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the OmitXmlDeclaration setting, and it does offer a different approach. As it would require more steps/changes and not feel any cleaner I think I will stick with my original method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Codor for your answer and discussion which helped me figure this out even though my code looks quite different from the code in the question.

My XmlDocument also had an XML declaration, so this worked for me:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(templateFilename);
doc.InsertAfter(doc.CreateDocumentType("html", null, null, null), doc.FirstChild);
```

Otherwise, i suppose i would have used `PrependChild()` rather than `InsertAfter()`.